# Django form wizard unique URL design

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard, formwizard

I am having a 5-step signup form, where first step is embedded into the home page. So step1 is part of home page and rest of the steps follow through. I like to have unique URLs for step2 to step5. Based on this I tried to design the URLS but I am stuck on how to leave the first step to be the home URL(mysite.com) and rest have something like mysite.com/signup/step2 etc.

This used to be my single working URL previously

```
from apps.profile.views.login import SignupWizard, SIGNUP_FORMS
    from apps.profile.forms import MultiPartSignupFormStep1, MultiPartSignupFormStep2, MultiPartSignupFormStep3, MultiPartSignupFormStep4,MultiPartSignupFormStep5

urlpatterns = patterns('apps.profile.views.login',
        url(r'^$', SignupWizard.as_view(SIGNUP_FORMS), name="signup"),
)
```

This is my present code

```
from apps.profile.views.login import SignupWizard, SIGNUP_FORMS
from apps.profile.forms import MultiPartSignupFormStep1, MultiPartSignupFormStep2, MultiPartSignupFormStep3, MultiPartSignupFormStep4,MultiPartSignupFormStep5
named_forms = (
    ('step1', MultiPartSignupFormStep1),
    ('step2', MultiPartSignupFormStep2),
    ('step3', MultiPartSignupFormStep3),
    ('step4', MultiPartSignupFormStep4),
    ('step5', MultiPartSignupFormStep5),
)

wizard = SignupWizard.as_view(named_forms)
    #url_name='step1', done_step_name='finished')

urlpatterns = patterns('apps.profile.views.login',
    url(r'^account/signup/(?P<step>.+)/$', wizard),
    #url(r'^account/signup/$', wizard),

)
```

How to have step1 as home URL and Unique URLs for rest of the steps?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would work:

```
from apps.profile.views.login import SignupWizard, SIGNUP_FORMS
from apps.profile.forms import MultiPartSignupFormStep1, MultiPartSignupFormStep2, MultiPartSignupFormStep3, MultiPartSignupFormStep4,MultiPartSignupFormStep5

step1 = (('step1', MultiPartSignupFormStep1),)
other_steps = (
    ('step2', MultiPartSignupFormStep2),
    ('step3', MultiPartSignupFormStep3),
    ('step4', MultiPartSignupFormStep4),
    ('step5', MultiPartSignupFormStep5),
)

wizard_step1 = SignupWizard.as_view(step1, url_name='wizard_step1')
wizard_other_steps = SignupWizard.as_view(other_steps, url_name='wizard_other_steps')

urlpatterns = patterns('apps.profile.views.login',
    url(r'^$', wizard_step1, name='wizard_step1'),
    url(r'^account/signup/(?P<step>.+)/$', wizard_other_steps, name='wizard_other_steps'),
)
```

Comment: I tried doing this but I get this error `URL name is needed to resolve correct wizard URLs`. I tried giving unique names but still its not resolving.

Comment: I tried, I am geting the same error. I guess it has to do something with the `NamedUrlWizardView`,which I am using in the login views to define Singupwizard.